# Trying to make a CodeIgniter controller called "List"

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, reserved-words

I have the following code in controllers/list.php:

```
<?php
class List extends Controller { 
    function index()
    {
        echo "hi";
    }
}
?>
```

However, trying to access it gives me the following PHP error:

**Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected T_LIST, expecting T_STRING in **/var/www/sitename/htdocs/system/application/controllers/list.php** on line **3**

Renaming the file to "example.php" and replacing "class List" with "class Example" works perfectly fine... my first thought was maybe "List" was a reserved name, but I checked CI's list of reserved names [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html) and it's not there.

I know I could fix the problem by just calling the thing something else but I really want my controller to be called "list" if at all possible. Any ideas, or insight into why this is happening?

Thanks,
Mala

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) is a reserved word in PHP, so you'll have to use something else. You can probably use a custom route to change the url if you really need to.

Comment: made the same mistake...i think everyone makes that mistake at least once.

Comment: Yeah this is a real bummer - the "list" word was totally wasted on a bizarre language construct for assigning variables multiple variables in a single statement.

Answer (score 1):

[list](https://www.php.net/list) is a built-in php construct