# naming a codeigniter function as class

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I have a codeigniter function which I would like to name as "class" as follows:

```
public function class($class_id = NULL)
    {
        ...
```

This will result in a url looking something like `domain.com/mydir/class/1`

I'm guessing "class" is reserved though.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to make a CodeIgniter controller called "List"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014524/trying-to-make-a-codeigniter-controller-called-list)

Comment: Use a route to get around this, you can't have a function named `class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter's [routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) can help you achieve this. You can't name a function `class` as it is a [reserved word](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).

For example, if you renamed the function in your question to `get_class` in a controller called `welcome`, then you could use the following route in *application/config/routes.php*

```
$route['mydir/class/(:num)'] = "welcome/get_class/$1";
```

This would route a URL such as `domain.com/mydir/class/1`, (assuming the root of the application is *domain.com*), with the final parameter being a number, to the `welcome` controller and the `get_class` function, passing *1* as the parameter.